# ¿Cómo ingresar datos por teclado en phyton?

Tags: python

tengo una pregunta acerca del ingreso de datos por teclado en phyton, tengo el siguiente código:

```
print('INGRESE SALARIO BASE:')

salarioBase = float(input())

print('INGRESE CANTIDAD DE HORAS EXTRA, PERO SINO REALIZO NINGUNA, DIGITE 0:')

horasExtras = float(input())

print('SI TUVO BONIFICACIONES DIGITE 1, SINO 0:')

bonificaciones = float(input())
horaTrabajo = float(salarioBase/185)

valorHorasExtras = horaTrabajo+(horaTrabajo*0.35)

horasExtrasTrabajadas = horasExtras*valorHorasExtras

valorDeBonificaciones = 0

if bonificaciones == 1:

    valorDeBonificaciones = (salarioBase*0.025)

else:

    pass

valorSalarioTotal = salarioBase+horasExtrasTrabajadas+valorDeBonificaciones

salud = (valorSalarioTotal*0.055)

pension = (valorSalarioTotal*0.055)

cajaCompensacion = (valorSalarioTotal*0.03)

total = valorSalarioTotal-(salud+pension+cajaCompensacion)

print('SU SALARIO FINAL ES:')

total = round(total, 1)

print(total)

print('SU SALARIO ANTES DE LOS DESCUENTOS DE LEY ES:')

valorSalarioTotal = round(valorSalarioTotal, 1)

print(valorSalarioTotal)
```

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que el usuario ingrese tres datos, pero no quiero que los ingrese presionando enter, sino, con la tecla espacio, ¿es posible? y si si lo es, podrían explicarme como se realiza, gracias!

Tengo una condición:

- Cada caso de prueba se especifica en una única línea.

Comment: si se puede, pero tendrás que usar modulos externos, podrias indicar que es lo que quieres realizar con eso? tal vez haya una mejor forma de solucionar tu problema

Comment: Básicamente necesito que cada dato que ingrese, lo ingrese con un espacio y no con un enter, ya edité la pregunta y ya esta el código completo para que veas lo que quiero realizar con esos datos. Un ejemplo es que al ingresar los datos se vea así: 1000 2 0

Comment: Ya tienes una respuesta y es la misma que yo te daría, si te sirvió aceptala

Answer (score 3):

Bienvenida Laura. Si bien podríamos darte la solución aplicada directamente en tu código(dártelo ya hecho), seria muy bueno que intentes aplicar la solución por tu cuenta. Te ayudará a razonarlo según los casos que se te presenten en distintas situaciones.

Respecto directamente a tu duda:

> Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que el usuario ingrese tres datos,
> pero no quiero que los ingrese presionando enter, sino, con la tecla
> espacio, ¿es posible?

La respuesta concreta es **SI**.

**¿Cómo podría resolverlo?**

Podríamos hacer un "artificio" usando *split()* ya que tu pauta es que los datos estén separados por espacios. Un ejemplo muy simple y práctico de lo que necesitas es el siguiente:

```
print('datos: ')

# almacenamos los 3 datos separados por espacios
datos = input()

# separamos los valores segun el caracter del espacio (" ") y los almacenamos en una lista
valoresDivididos = datos.split(" ")

# mostramos  las 3 posiciones de la lista, cada una con los valores que se ingresaron
print("valor 1: ", valoresDivididos[0])
print("valor 2: ", valoresDivididos[1])
print("valor 3: ", valoresDivididos[2])
```

Puedes aplicarlo directamente a tu lógica. Una vez separados puedes usarlos para lo que necesites.